# How ASLR randomizes address space in Linux

Tags: linux, operating-system, aslr

I'm trying to find out how ASLR in Linux works, I have written a simple c program like below:

```
void simple(void)
{
    printf("simple func\n");
}
int main(void)
{
    simple();

    printf("address is %p \n.", (void*)&simple);

    return 0;
}
```

in the above code, I simply print the location address of simple function, and in all execution of the above code I get the same address for simple function but due to ASLR, I expect to get a random address for simple function in each execution of the program? am I wrong and ASLR should not do this?
of course when I ran "ldd app.o" I get a random address each time for different libraries.

Comment: Can you use a correct format specifier (e.g. use "`%p`" instead of "`%x`" and cast the function pointer to `(void *)`)? When the format specifier says its an `int` you probably only print the lowest 32 bits and can't tell if the highest bits of a 64-bit pointer were randomized. Note that the lowest 12 bits (and maybe more) will not be randomized due to the way paging works.

Comment: @Brendan Thanks for your response, I have applied your advice, but  I got the same result again.

Comment: I get random addresses when I run your program, that change from one run to the next.  Perhaps you have ASLR disabled?  What do you see when you do `cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`?

Comment: I see 2 when executing "cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space" command.

Comment: @alirezasadeghpour What is the specific address you're seeing? If it's a low value like `0x401132` you may be on a distro that doesn't compile PIEs by default. Use `gcc -pie app.c` in this case

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you, I was seeing address like "0x10434" in fedora and raspbian distro, but after compiling with "gcc -pie app.c" I can see randomness in the address. thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora/CentOS/Redhat and presumably other distros are configured to build with `-no-pie` (Position Independent Executables) by default, which prevents ASLR of the executable itself.

You can explicitly enable it with `-pie`:

```
gcc -pie app.c -o app && ./app
```